# How to colour rows in a dataframe using style.applymap()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, rows

I want to colour both the 'Grand Total' row and the 'Total' column in a DataFrame object `df`, for which I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Function to set background highlight colour.
def bg_colour (val):
    colour = '#ffff00'
    return 'background-color: %s' % colour

df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A','B','C','D','Grand Total'], 'Total': [1,2,3,4,10]})
t1 = df.style.applymap(bg_colour, subset = ['Total'])
dfT = df.T
dfT = dfT.style.applymap(bg_colour, subset = [4])
t1T = t1.T
```

However, when the compiler reaches the last line of the code, the following error arises:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-c0c380b9c518> in <module>
      12 dfT = dfT.style.applymap(bg_colour, subset = [4])
      13 display(dfT)
 ---> 14 t1T = t1.T
 
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'T'
```

From what I understand, `style.applymap()` implicitly converts DataFrame into a Styler-type object, which cannot be further manipulated as a DataFrame.

**Question 1**: How can both rows and columns of a DataFrame object be coloured?

**Question 2**: How can a Styler-type object be converted into a DataFrame-type one?

Comment: Also see [pandas styling](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+color+rows+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk03hi1m_tSuyftTaqnxtGulhTr_llw:1597186534853&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj37LAn5TrAhXWJzQIHT8jB34QrQIoBHoECAEQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)

Comment: I don't think the question in the dup link solve the problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style object returns an HTML-formatted string, so I don't think it's straight forward to turn it into a dataframe. Instead of `applymap`, I would rewrite the function so as it takes a column/row as argument and use `apply`. Something like this:

```
def bg_colour_col (col):
    colour = '#ffff00'
    return ['background-color: %s' % colour 
                if col.name=='Total' or i==4   # color column `Total` or row `4`
                else ''
             for i,x in col.iteritems()]

df.style.apply(bg_colour_col)
```

Output:

[image]